# pydev: cannot set correct libraries

Tags: python, libraries, pydev

pydev 8.0.1
python version used by pydev is 3.7.4 (platform.python_version())
Which is wrong. My installed version is 3.8.5.
When I click on "choose from list" in eclipse preferences -> pydev -> Interpreters -> Python Interpreters it shows only Python 3.7 libraries. No way to setup the correct 3.8 libraries.
"echo pythonpath" in command line gives usr/lib/python3.8
I put "38" in "String substitution variables" for "PY"
I am blocked. Any clue someone?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this case, click for `Browse for python/pypy exe` and select the actual Python 3.8 executable you want to work with.

[image]

i.e.: `Choose from list` uses some heuristics to find the installed versions of python in your machine, but in this case it seems it's not finding it (but that should be ok since you can manually choose any other python executable).

Comment: Hi @fabio-zadrozny  thanks for your answer. But I did what you suggest and pydev still only finds the 3.7 libraries. I guess the issue is due to lack of support of 3.8 yet and the so call "heuristic" you mention. For the time being I solved my issue by selecting the 3.7 executable so as to be aligned with the libraries.